# convert three way circuit to two single pole circuits

Tags: electrical, wiring

[image][image]I have two three way switches within arms reach of each other for the overhead lamp in a small hallway.  I want to take them out and replace them with single poles the second to operate under cabinet lighting.  I intend to use one of the travelers for the switched hot to the overhead and the other to extend the hot lead to the switch in the other box.  Will that be a problem?

Comment: How is the 3-way currently wired (including the neutral)?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes?

Comment: The desired result is:  In the first box there 2 x 14-2 w/g and 1 x 14-3 w/g.  All three neutrals are nutted together without a pigtail, all three grounds are nutted together with a pigtail to the single pole switch, and the two 14-2 hot leads are nutted together with a pigtail to the screw down terminal of the switch.  On the same side of the switch the black traveler wire of the 14-3 cable is in the push in terminal.  The red traveler of the 14-3 cable is screwed to the other side of the switch.

Comment: The second box (the boxes may be shown in reverse order in the post) has the neutral wire from the cables to the overhead lamp and the under cabinet lamps nutted to the 14-3 neutral, no pigtail.  The red traveler of the 14-3 is nutted to the hot wire for the overhead ceiling lamp and the black traveler is screwed to the single pole switch opposite the hot wire for the under cabinet lamps (screw in terminal).  All three cables' grounds are nutted together with a pigtail to the switch.

Comment: What I meant by "The desired result is:  "  is that I am showing the boxes in the after view, not how they started out.  I'd still like to know if that's alright.  Specifically feeding two hot wires, one switched and one not, through the 14-3 cable.